# How to programmatically set description in simple associated products?

Tags: database, programmatically, product-description

I need set description in all associated products of specific configurable product and with this code all it's ok except part of code where I insert description in associated products on database.

What command do I use on "**how to set description in database**"

```
<?php

define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());

require "app/Mage.php";

Mage::init();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

try {

    $configProductIds = [1462];

    foreach ($configProductIds as $product_id) {

        $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $description = $configProduct->getDescription();

        $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable');
        $childIds = $childIds->getChildrenIds($configProduct->getId())[0];

        foreach ($childIds as $childId) {

            $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($childId);
            // how to set description in database
            $childProduct->save();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print_r($e->getMessage());
    echo "<br><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the description, you just simply add below code:

```
$childProduct->setDescription('your description here');
```